# Where is var/jenkins_home folder located?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I am running Jenkins inside docker container on Ubuntu. I tried to access jenkins initial password from var/jenkins_home folder by `docker -it exec CONTAINER_ID bash` and `cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`. I know how to access the folder and see what is inside var/jenkins_home but I want to understand where it is located. I cannot find it inside my local VM and I have not setup docker hub credentials. So, where it is actually located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-data
```

or

```
/your/home:/var/jenkins_home
```

Comment: I cannot access the docker folder here /var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-data. It says _You do not have the necessary permissions to view contents of "docker"_. I have not mapped the volume to my host so there is no var folder at /home.

Comment: Ah, well then now at least you know where you can find it. Try adjusting permissions?

Comment: I could reach jenkins_home after fixing the permissions and reinstalling Jenkins

Comment: Good to hear that it helped!

Comment: @mroWsymaS Thanks a lot! "/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins-data" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this   /var/lib/docker/jenkins-data

Comment: I did not have access to docker folder which I fixed with `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/lib`. But when I opened the folder I don

Comment: jenkins_home folder is not inside docker. It has following folder inside:  builders  buildkit  containers  image  network  overlay2  runtimes  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes

Answer (score 0):

By Default Jenkins docker images are installed Jenkins in below path

```
/var/lib/docker/
```

also, you can install Jenkins docker according to your suitable path using below method:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

If launched with docker, and if in your run command you put "volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home", then try this :

- docker container exec -it JENKINS_CONTAINER_ID bash
  then once connected :
- cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

it'll show up the password you're looking for.